# How do I join these 3 tables, do a sum calculation and group by multiple values?

Tags: sql

So I have these 3 tables below:

**User Table:**

[image]

**Deposit Table:**

[image]

**Withdrawal Table:**

[image]

Question:
How do I join these 3 tables together, having the values grouped by:

1. Month
2. Sex
3. Age
4. State

**Expected Output:**

[image]

As seen from my expected output above, I want to separate these users into different buckets

i.e.
Month: January, Sex: F, Age: 18, State: Arizona (Bucket 1)
Month: January, Sex: M, Age: 21, State: Texas (Bucket 2)

and find the sum(Deposit.amount) & sum (Withdrawal.amount) group by the fields above ^
as well as how many users are in this bucket.

*Clarification:*
"Month" column in my Expected Ouput is based on Transaction Month for both Deposit & Withdrawal table combined, I just added the "Account Created Month" column in User table just in case its possible to do a 3-table join through Month values.

Comment: Please don't tag conflicting RDBMS. Just tag the one you are using, and *only* that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```sql
SELECT tr.Month, u.Sex, u.Age, u.Stage
   , Sum(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'D' THEN tr.Amount ELSE 0 END) As [Total Deposit Amount]
   , Sum(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'W' THEN tr.Amount ELSE 0 END) As [Total Withdrawal Amount]
   , COUNT(distint u.UserID) As [Number of Users in this Category]
FROM (
    SELECT userid, [Deposit Amount] As Amount, [Transaction Month] As Month, 'D' As [Type] FROM [Deposit]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT userid, [Withdrawal Amount], [Transaction Month], 'W' FROM [Withdrawal]
) tr
INNER JOIN User u ON u.UserID = tr.UserId
GROUP BY tr.Month, u.Sex, u.Age, u.State
```

Really, deposits and withdrawals should be the same table (Transactions) to begin with, where the only difference is withdrawals are negative.

---

Also... **please** stop using images to represent your sample data and results. It makes things so much harder on us to help you, which makes it less likely you'll get a good or prompt answer.